# HLS AAC 5.1 audio not working on Chromecast 2 and Chromecast Ultra with firmware 1.28.100555

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I am unable to play HLS video with 5.1 audio track on Chromecast 2 and Chromecat Ultra. The same files worked just fine on previous firmware releases before 1.28.100555.

In order to avoid any Objective-C programming errors all the tests I made were done using a slightly modified "CastVideos-ios" (official sample from Google Cast SDKs github).
The only modification I made is related to "media_list_1_url" in order to make the application load a custom JSON file pointing to my video sample files.
The JSON list is available at this link:

http://144.76.13.14/GoogleCastTestList.json

When I try to play the 5.1 audio track version on Chromecast 2 and Chromecast Ultra the video simply dose not load. Both of the test files play without problems on Chromecast 1.

Can someone help me find out if this is a Chromecast firmware issue or I must modify the Cast sender app code in order to play 5.1 audio files ?

Comment: Please file a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc

Comment: dash is working for you?

Comment: Related: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/n6ag2giHHLA;context-place=topicsearchin/chromecast/category$3Aios and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69499192